# Which pattern to generify instantiation of objects that have different Ctor arguments

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

I would like to construct a robot with or without a tool, a mobile base, and other parts. As I want to automatize the configuration of the parts, I have a class Robot with the parts as template arguments

For instance, in the code below, the code will build as long as we use tools that have the same constructor signature as ToolInterface. It does build with a Screwdriver but does not with a Gripper.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class BaseRobot
{
public:
    BaseRobot(){};
};

class ToolInterface
{
public:
    ToolInterface(BaseRobot* _base, std::string _name):name{_name}{/*register _base*/};
    std::string name;
    bool param_1;
    char param_2;
};

template<class T, class... Args>
constexpr T* construct(Args... args)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, nullptr_t>::value)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        return new T(args...);
    }
};

template<class Tool>
class Robot : public BaseRobot
{
protected:
    Tool* tool;
public:
    Robot():tool(construct<Tool>(this, "tool")){   // <--- here is my problem !!
        if constexpr (! std::is_same<Tool, nullptr_t>::value)
        {
            //do stuff on/with tool->param_1, tool->param_2, ...
            std::cout << "tool configured" << std::endl;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "no tool" << std::endl;
    };
};

class Screwdriver: public ToolInterface
{
public:
    Screwdriver(BaseRobot* _base, std::string _name):ToolInterface(_base, _name){};
};

class Gripper: public ToolInterface
{
public:
    Gripper(BaseRobot* _base, std::string _name, bool _reversed):
        ToolInterface(_base, _name)
        ,reversed{_reversed}{};
    bool reversed;
};

int main()
{
    Robot<Screwdriver> robot_screwdriver;
    Robot<nullptr_t> robot_null;
    //Robot<Gripper> robot_gripper;     //does not build

    return 0;
}
```

Here are some ideas :

1. using a ToolConfig struct that is passed as an argument of Tools. If a tool requires more arguments, one should subclass ToolConfig and cast it into the tool constructor (see below): damn, that looks cumbersome and ugly!
2. enforce inherited ToolInterface classes Ctor signature: some tools must have a different Ctor signature
3. using a variadic template to pass args into the template: not reasonable because, in the end, I want something like `template<class Tool1, class Tool2, class MobileBase, class Camera> class Robot`

solution 1 would look like

```
struct ToolConfig
{
    std::string name;
};
struct GripperConfig : public ToolConfig
{
    bool reversed;
};
class Gripper : public ToolInterface
{
public:
    Gripper(ToolConfig& _config):
        ToolInterface(_config)
        ,reversed{static_cast<GripperConfig&>(_config).reversed}{};
    bool reversed;
};
```

Do you have a magic pattern to solve my problem? Is my pattern wrong?

Comment: How should the Griper know the value of `_reversed`?

Comment: Why can't you just pass in the already constructed tools into the Robot constructor?

Comment: I edited my post : I cannot construct tools before the robot because I need to use robot instance into the tool Ctor

Comment: But where do you want to pass the additional constructor args? In the Robot constructor, I guess, right?

Comment: And will the `MobileBase` and `Camera` use the same pattern?

Comment: I could pass the additional Ctor args into the Robot constructor, yes.
MobileBase and Camera will use the same pattern as Tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use tuple instead of struct, not ideal but this works as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>


class BaseRobot
{
public:
    BaseRobot() {};
};

class ToolInterface
{
public:
    ToolInterface(std::string _name) :name{ _name } {/*register _base*/ };
    std::string name;
    bool param_1;
    char param_2;
};


template <typename T, typename ... Types, std::size_t ... Indices>
constexpr T* apply_impl(const std::tuple<Types...>& tuple, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
{
    return new T(std::get<Indices>(tuple)...);
}


template <typename T, typename ... Types>
constexpr T* apply(const std::tuple<Types...>& tuple)
{
    return apply_impl<T>(tuple, std::index_sequence_for<Types...>());
}


template<class T, class... Args>
constexpr T* construct(std::tuple<Args...> args)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, nullptr_t>::value)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        return apply<T>(args);
    }
}


template<class Tool>
class Robot : public BaseRobot
{
protected:
    Tool* tool;
public:
    template<class ...Args1>  //, class ...Args2> 
    Robot(std::tuple<Args1...> p1):  // , std::tuple<Args2...> p2):
    tool(construct<Tool>(p1))
    {   // <--- here is my problem !!
        if constexpr (!std::is_same<Tool, nullptr_t>::value)
        {
            //do stuff on/with tool->param_1, tool->param_2, ...
            std::cout << "tool configured" << std::endl;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "no tool" << std::endl;
    };
};

class Screwdriver : public ToolInterface
{
public:
    Screwdriver(std::string _name) :ToolInterface(_name) {};
};

class Gripper : public ToolInterface
{
public:
    Gripper(std::string _name, bool _reversed) :
        ToolInterface(_name)
        , reversed{ _reversed }{};
    bool reversed;
};

int main()
{
    using p1 = std::tuple<std::string>;
    Robot<Screwdriver> robot_screwdriver(p1{"sdvr"});

    return 0;
}
```

Could be improved I agree.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass factory lambdas that generate your tools in the initializer.

```
template<typename Func>
Robot(Func f):tool(f(this, "tool")){   // <--- here is my problem !!
    if constexpr (! std::is_same<Tool, std::nullptr_t>::value)
    {
        //do stuff on/with tool->param_1, tool->param_2, ...
        std::cout << "tool configured" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "no tool" << std::endl;
};
```

The call site would look like this:

```
Robot<Screwdriver> robot_screwdriver([](auto... args){ return new Screwdriver(args...); });
Robot<std::nullptr_t> robot_null([](auto...){ return nullptr; });
Robot<Gripper> robot_gripper([](auto... args){ return new Gripper(args..., true); });
```

Not exactly beautiful, but it works.

See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Te86TK) for a full example. Does this solve your problem?

If you can use c++17, you can add a class template deduction guide to reduce some of the redundancy at the call site.

Comment: Yes, it is solution 3. It does not handle the construction of multiple tools that have different args.

Comment: I've edited my question to provide a different solution.